# Using Javascript regex, how to get a value between some phrase..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In my url, i'm suppose to get the token number, but the token number may be Numeric or Alpha. I need to get the token always in different scenario. How do I achieve that using Regular Expressions?

Sample URLs:

```
?&token=1905477219/someother/stuff

&token=1905477219

&token=xyzbacsfhsaof

&token=xyzbacsfhsaof/some/other
```

How can I always get the token from these kind of URLs?

I tried this:

```
/(token=.*)/g
```

I am looking for :

```
?&token=1905477219/someother/stuff - in this case "1905477219"
```

and

`&token=xyzbacsfhsaof - in this case "xyzbacsfhsaof"` .. like so

But it's not working. Can any one can help me?

Thanks all, this is working fine for me:

```
var reg = window.location.href.match(/token=([^\/]*)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern to match any token with a Latin letter or decimal digit:

```
/token=([a-z0-9]*)/
```

Or this which will allow the token to contain any character other than `/`:

```
/token=([^\/]*)/
```

Note that unless you expect to capture multiple tokens, the global modifier (`g`) is not necessary.

Comment: @3gwebtrain You just have to change where you put the parenthesis; see my updated answer.

Comment: I tested, still i am getting like this: "token=1905477219" - instead "1905477219"

Comment: @3gwebtrain How are you getting that value? `/token=([a-z0-9]*)/.exec("token=1905477219")[1]` will result in `"1905477219"`.

Comment: it works fine to me: window.location.href.match(/token=([^\/]*)/)[1];

Answer (score 1):

```
/token=(\w*)/g
```

without the token

```
/token=(\w*)/.exec("token=1905477219")[1]
/token=(\w*)/.exec("token=1905477219/somestuff")[1]
/token=(\w*)/.exec("somestuf/token=1905477219")[1]
/token=(\w*)/.exec("somestuf/token=1905477219/somestuff")[1]

// all will return 1905477219
```

this will capture letters, numbers and underscores while stopping at the forward slash if present